# All Shortest Paths To A Given Vertex

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

Given a directed graph G=(V,E) and a weight function w : E - > R+  (only positive weights for edges in the graph) , I need to find all the shortest paths from every vertex v in V to a given vertex k.

I've thought about reversing the edges in the graph and then running [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) from the vertex k. I wonder whether a shortest path p from k to v1 is actually the shortest path from v1 to k in the original graph ( before reversing edges ).

I'd be grateful if anyone could explain if and why it does / does not happen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have anything formal at the moment, but yes, your idea should be good. Consider what would happen if the graph was undirected: the two paths would obviously be the same. What you are suggesting basically leads to an undirected graph, so the two are the same.

Comment: That's also what I've thought about , but I wonder whether there is a certain situation where it won't happen.

Comment: The validity of this directly follows from the symmetry that you produce by reversing edges. You're fine.

Comment: For each statement about a directed graph, there's a dual statement about the graph with all edges reversed. Yours is an example of this.

Comment: There's things that are difficult to prove because they are too obvious. (I recall that Knuth had a nice rant about it.) This is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

(This won't be the most formal proof in the world, but hopefully its good enough to convince yourself).

Lets say for a vertex *v*, in graph *G*, the shortest path from *v* to *k* is of length *m*.
The two things you want to know are:
 1. In the reversed graph, G*, there is a path of length *m* from *k* to *v*.
 2. In the reversed graph, G*, there are no paths from *k* to *v* that are shorter than *m*.

Before I start, can we take one thing on faith:
*Lemma 1*: If you have a directed path from vertex *v* to vertex *w*, and you reverse every edge on the path, then you have a path from vertex *w* to vertex *v*. This is provable, but I think its fairly common sense. I'll prove it if you want me to.

For point 1: Consider the path in *G* from *v* to *k* consisting of *m* edges. If you reverse each of these edges, you will have a path from *k* to *v* of length *m* (by *Lemma 1*).

For point 2: Suppose there exists a path in the reversed graph G*, from *k* to *v* of length *n* < *m*. If you reverse this path, then there is a path of length *n* from *v* to *k* (*Lemma 1*). This means that there is a path from *v* to *k* in the original graph that is shorter than *m*, contradicting the statement that the path of length *m* is the shortest.

Comment: Or, abstracted: Paths are the same length after being reversed. So if one path from a to b is shorter than another path from a to b, then it's also the shorter path from b to a once they've been reversed.